# Ignore Puppeteer arg "--remote-debugging-port=0"

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, remote-debugging

I was wondering why the arg "--remote-debugging-port=0" is still on even though I called it between the ignoreDefaultArgs of the browser.

Here's my script

```
(async()=>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath:"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
        headless:false,
        devtools:false,
        ignoreDefaultArgs:[
            '--remote-debugging-port=0',
        ],
        args:[
            '--user-data-dir=C:/Users/GIULIO/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 2',
        ]
    })
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
    await page.goto('chrome://version/')
```

And here's what I get when I go to `chrome://version`

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to remove that?

Comment: Because I don't need it and I find strange that it persists even though it shouldn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--remote-debugging-port` is part of the wiring puppeteer needs to set up to be able to connect to chrome. Puppeteer can connect to chrome in two ways:

- Using pipes `puppeteer.launch({pipe: true});`. This will add the flag `--remote-debugging-pipe`.
- Using WebSockets `puppeteer.launch({pipe: false});`. This will add the flag `--remote-debugging-port=0`. Which will tell Chromium that remote debugging is required and that he can pick any free port.

There is no way to get rid of any of these flags because it's part of the basic communication.

Comment: Oh I see,so there's no way to disable both of the flags right? Because they are needed to allow puppeteer to use chrome